# Searching through every file in a directory (and in any sub-directories) one by one

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I'm trying to loop through every file in a directory (including files in its subdirectories) and perform some action if the file meets an if-condition.

Part of my code is as follows:

```
for f in $direc/*
do
        if grep -q 'search_term' $f; then
            #action on this file
        fi
done
```

However, this fails in the case of subdirectories. I would be very grateful if someone could help me out.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `-R` option to grep will read all files in the directory tree including subdirectories. Combined with the `-l` option to print only the matching file names, you can use that to perform an action on each file that matches.

```
egrep -Rl pattern directory | while read path; do echo $path && mv $path /tmp; done
```

For example, that would print the file name and move the file to a different directory.

Answer (score 0):

Find | xargs is the usual pattern I use, and has the advantage of not getting hung up on special characters in file names (spaces etc.) if you use the -print0 option of find.

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} sh -c "if grep -q 'search string' '{}'; then cmd-to-run '{}'; fi"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes because with this syntax, `grep` expect to process file(s) not directories. Minimal change to your script would be to test if `$f` is a file or not:

```
...
if [ -f "$f" ] && grep -q 'search_term' $f; then
...
```

In reality you would probably want to get list of files with patter match and act on those:

```
while read f; do
    : #action on file file $f
done < <(grep -rl 'search_term' $direc/)
```

I've opted for getting the get the list of files through `<(list)` because piping it into `while` would cause the inside of your loop to run in another process (which could be a problem in particular if you expect any variable (changes) to be accessible from outside. And unlike simple for with ``` `` ``` it's not as as sensitive to what filenames you encounter (namely I have spaces in mind, this would still get confused by newlines though). Speaking of which:

```
while read -d "" f; do
    : #action on file file $f
done < <(grep -rZl 'search_term' $direc/)
```

Nothing should be able to confuse that, as entries are nul character delimited and that one just must not appear in a file name.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no newlines in your file names:

```
find "$direc" -type f -exec grep -q 'search_term' {} \; -print |
while IFS= read -r f; do
    #action on this file
done
```